# Can a websites render differently in a maximized browser window v.s. a custom size window of the same size

Tags: scaling, screen-resolution, screen-size

Currently I am looking for a potential monitor replacement. I am interested in a super wide screen (3840 x 1080, 32:9) based on the following idea:

With windows FancyZones (part of PowerToys) I create a 1080 x 1920 tile in the middle of the screen. The space that is left on both sides will have their own tile.

I am a test engineer, so I thought with this I can mimick a full screen browser in the middle where I display the website or webapp to test. At the sides I will have for example a test protocol, documentation and/or mail client.

Point is that I need to make sure it does not matter for the shown layout of a webpage if it is displayed in a maximized browser window on a 1080 x 1920 screen, or in a 1080 x 1920 tile, where the window in fact is not maximized (but has the same size).

Are there websites that (can) do stuff differently if a screen is maximized or not, instead of just looking at the window size itself?

Comment: There’s no way to know if a browser is maximized or not

Comment: Bear in mind that for most users with a single 1080x1920 monitor (or equivalent) the maximized browser window will lose some space for the task bar. I haven't played with the PowerToys but I imagine the region you're setting up will not have that space loss, so there may be minor differences if you don't take that into account.

Comment: Maybe related (however i don't know if 2018's answer is still relevant) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49003290/detect-if-browser-window-is-maximized-and-at-default-100-zoom

Comment: Indeed a maximized window means 1080 x 1920 minus the task bar. This will be the same for the maximized window and the FancyZone tile.

So resolution is exactly the same between both I think.

Comment: Devtools have a way to “resize” to various resolutions

Comment: Although I sometimes want to test on different resolutions, this question is not about that.

It simply boils down to: "Can a website know that a browser window is in maximized state or do layout changes only occur based on window size?".

However "Daniel" you also already said a website cannot know if a browser window is in maximized state, so that would mean that how a website is displayed would never differ between a maximized window and a not maximized window of the same size. Is that correct?